# How to update facebook page likes when a new like is made by user?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-login, facebook-access-token

Ok so I have a website where people login through facebook and they give access to the their liked pages,which is stored in my websites database,but the problem is what if a new page is liked,i could make a query now and then to fetch the new likes if new pages is liked by using an extended token,but the query will be useless if no new like is made,Is there any way that the system only goes and fetches when there is a new like done by the user and the system inserts it or any way that the app that is actually in facebook sent request to my website that a new like is made by the user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible with the Realtime API, it includes a "likes" object for User object subscription: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.2

How it works:

- You subscribe to the `subscriptions` endpoint with an App Token: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/app/subscriptions
- After subscribing, you will get a POST object sent to the specified callback for every change

Comment: can you explain with relation to access tokens how this thing actually works

Comment: i will add a basic explanation in the answer

Comment: can it be done also for friends that whenever a user in by db and another user in my db (who were not friends) be friends it will let me know by this way ?

Comment: then what can be done in that situation or what if a page is unliked by a user or someone unfriend someone,is a there any ways to get this type of  works done ?

Comment: you can subscribe to the user likes, so that one is possible to check for. and there is a "friends" object subscription too. sorry, did not realize that there IS one for friends, so my comment was not correct.

Comment: last ques,so subscribing gives me about likes or unlikes and get new friends or gets unfriended right ?